# Given total number of hours, how to find the working hours per day so as to finish the work with the total number of days?

Tags: algorithms, modular-arithmetic, contest-math

I am given total number of days(d).I am also given 'n' numbers each representing how many hours of work I can do on the i'th day.Now I have to find the minimum number of work rate(hours/per day) that I can use to finish the work within the total number of days. Example:- n = 4(total days for working) and d= 5(deadline number of days) Hours of work needed per i'th day = 7 3 2 4. Here, I can dedicate 2 days to the first day(7) so that I can finish the work in 5 days at a rate of 4 hours/day. Now, I have come up with a loop that would loop over the speeds from 1 and as soon as I find a speed which manages to finish all the work in 5 days, then I break out of it and print it.However, I was wondering if there is a better way/faster way to solve this problem.
EDIT-It seems as if the question was not clear.So, what I have to do is I have to is to find the minimum work rate at which I can complete each days work within the given deadline(d).I CAN allot more than 1 day to finish off a days work if that helps me to get a lower work rate.

Comment: Hi, since you seem to be new here: Please take a look at some markdown basics so you can format your question properly (a.k.a. 'help us to help you' ;)). This is very hard to read...

Comment: Okay I will try to explain my question using an example.
Suppose I am given n = 4 and d = 5.The values in my array are - 7 4 2 3.
These values are the number of hours I need to work on the i'th day where i is the index of the array.
That means I have 5 days to finish of 4 days of work but have to do 7 hours on the first day, 4 hours on the second day and so on.Now, I have to choose the minimum work rate/hr such hat I can finish of the work in the given time period (d).So, here out of the 5 days,if I give 2 days to the first day, then I can finish off the work in 5 days at the rate of 4.

Comment: I think @polynomial_donut was trying to say that it would be easier for people to read your questions if you were using MathJax. Refer to this link for help: https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference

Comment: is the question still not clear?I think it would take me some time to learn the formatting and all.So please excuse my poor formatting skills this time.